# move and copy table data to another table data

Tags: python, django, model, copy, move

We have 3 tables(models) A,B and c.Table 'A' have data, if we delete the specific table data of 'A' then that deleted data i want to save in table 'B' automatically and
if we added the data in table 'C' we want that data is also added in table 'A' automatically.

```
from django.db import models

class Stock(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='AVAILABLE')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Product name:{0} Quantity:{1} Price:{2} Status:{3} '.format(self.product_name, self.quantity, self.price, self.status)
class Sale(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='SOLD')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Product name:{0} Quantity:{1} Price:{2} Status:{3}'.format(self.product_name, self.quantity, self.price, self.status)
class Purchase(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='Purchased')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Product name:{0} Quantity:{1} Price:{2} Status:{3}'.format(self.product_name,self.quantity, self.price, self.status)
```

Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `delete` method of `Stock` and override the `save` method of `Purchase` like this:

```
class Stock(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='AVAILABLE')

    def delete(self):
        Sale.objects.create(product_name=self.product_name, quantity=self.quantity, price=self.price, status=self.status)
        super().delete()

class Purchase(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='Purchased')

    def save(self):
        if not self.pk:
            Stock.objects.create(product_name=self.product_name, quantity=self.quantity, price=self.price, status=self.status)
        super().save()
```

Comment: what about model 'sale'?

Comment: `Sale` does not need modification because it has nothing that triggers an action. Notice in the `delete` method of `Stock` it creates a new `Sale` object because that's how you want the trigger to work per your requirement of "if we delete the specific table data of 'A' then that deleted data i want to save in table 'B' automatically".

Comment: Thank you sir  you solved my problem. django administration side working correct but not my actual web app side..if we delete the stock item, but that deleted items are not save in sale.

Comment: How does your actual web app delete `Stock`? Is it through `Stock.objects.delete()`, or it through the `delete()` method of an individual `Stock` object?

Comment: individual delete method. i created separate app for all model                                                def delete_stock(request, pk):

    Stock.objects.filter(id=pk).delete()

    items = Stock.objects.all()

    context = {
        'items': items
    }
    return render(request, 'index1.html', context)

Comment: That's actually not the individual `delete` method, but the `delete` method of the queryset, which in your case happens to delete only one object because of the `id=pk` constraint. There's no way to override the behavior of the `delete` method of the queryset because it's done in bulk directly at the SQL level. Luckily, in your case you can just modify it to `Stock.objects.get(id=pk).delete()` to invoke the individual `delete` method because you're deleting just one object at a time.